# Jboss-how to run multible web apps on diffrent ports

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jakarta-ee

i have to run 2 web apps on two diffrent ports , one on default  port 80 and other is on 89 port, i am using Jboss 4.2.3 , and i need to depoly both WARs to same JBoss intance.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this but I guess that this would involve declaring another `Connector`  in the Tomcat configuration (i.e. the `jbossweb.sar/server.xml` file).

But... what's the advantage to having more than one connector if they both process connections for the same container?

Comment: the other wep application for administration of backend solution , the port shouldn't be accessible from outside company interanet for security purposes

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is have separate instances of JBoss running on the same machine. This page explains how to achieve that: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine

Furthermore CodeRanch had a good thread on the subject of your question. (See here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/90653/JBoss/Deploy-web-apps-different-ports)
It might be worth reading if you are looking for a different solution than separate instances....